# Net Core Error The name 'Ok' does not exist in the current context

Tags: c#, asp.net-core

I am receiving the following error: The name 'Ok' does not exist in the current context.

How would I resolve this issue in my Controller API? Return Ok is already embedded in the controller.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Threading.Tasks;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using System.Net.Http;
using Newtonsoft.Json;
using WeatherTest.Models;

namespace WeatherChecker.Controllers
{

    public class WeatherData
    {
        [HttpGet("[action]/{city}")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> City(string city)
        {
            using (var client = new HttpClient())
            {
                try
                {
                    client.BaseAddress = new Uri("http://api.openweathermap.org");
                    var response = await client.GetAsync($"/data/2.5/weather?q={city}&appid=YOUR_API_KEY_HERE&units=metric");
                    response.EnsureSuccessStatusCode();

                    var stringResult = await response.Content.ReadAsStringAsync();
                    var rawWeather = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<OpenWeatherResponse>(stringResult);

                    // Error Here: ** The name 'Ok' does not exist in the current context **
                    return Ok(new
                    {
                        Temp = rawWeather.Main.Temp,
                        Summary = string.Join(",", rawWeather.Weather.Select(x => x.Main)),
                        City = rawWeather.Name
                    });
                }
                catch (HttpRequestException httpRequestException)
                {
                     // Error Here: The name 'BadRequest' does not exist in the current context
                    return BadRequest($"Error getting weather from OpenWeather: {httpRequestException.Message}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: You must inherit from `Controller` or `ControllerBase`

Answer (score 54, accepted):

With Attribute routing feature, aspnet support POCO controller. It allow to use any class as controller. But you will we lose all utilities and helpers provided by framework base classes.

The class `Controller` inherite from `ControllerBase` and add view support. In your case, `ControllerBase` is enough.

```
public class WeatherData : ControllerBase // <- 
{
    // ...
}
```