# The name 'Ok' does not exist in the current context, Razor Code behind

Tags: c#, asp.net, razor-pages

In my code behind I have the following and I'm getting the error 'Ok' does not exist in current context. I'm trying to populate a form with textboxes.

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetDetails(string custName)
{
    var x = _context.Customer
            .Join(_context.Sales, 
            x => x.CustId,
            c => c.CustId,
            (x,c) => new
            { 
                customerName = x.Name,
                address = x.Address,
                sale = x.SaleDate
            }).ToListArraySync();

         return Ok(await q.ToListArraySync()); //causes error 'Ok' doesn't exist in current context

}
```

I need to prefill the form on the page out with the data.  I'm able to get the data on the default OnGet(), however, I need  to join two tables in this handler

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Net Core Error The name 'Ok' does not exist in the current context](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52451416/net-core-error-the-name-ok-does-not-exist-in-the-current-context)

Comment: Not really, because my posted code works in my WebAPI, I'm trying to make it work in the code behind of my Razor View for a small POC project I'm  working on

Comment: A Razor Page wouldn't return an OK result like that. That'd go in a Web API controller.

Comment: @mason, I know, I'm trying to get the Razor page working with this query, and trying to figure out what to use instead  of return Ok() so it returns the data in JSON format, so I can show it on the web form.

Comment: Don't. That doesn't belong in a Razor page. Put it in a controller.

Comment: I was  trying to avoid doing that for this POC (it's something quick we're putting together) and this is the only page(view) showing data from two tables. This project if green lighted will go with the proper architecture design.

Comment: Even if it's a POC, it takes just a couple seconds to create a controller and put this logic in there.

Comment: I sometimes use json serialisation to populate a javascript variable. eg `var something = @Html.Raw(JsonSerializer.Serialize(Model.something));`

Answer (score 0):

You can "manually" return `OkObjectResult` or `JsonResult`. `ControllerBase.Ok` is just a convenience method that [actually returns an `OkObjectResult`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.aspnetcore.mvc.controllerbase.ok?view=aspnetcore-7.0#microsoft-aspnetcore-mvc-controllerbase-ok(system-object))

```cs
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetDetails(string custName)
{
    // ...

    return new OkObjectResult(await q.ToListArraySync());

    // or
    return new JsonResult(await q.ToListArraySync());
}
```

Answer (score -2):

I got it working.

I added a FK to the table and rebuilt the models and then this:

```
 public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetDetails(string custName)
{

        var x = _context.Customer
                .Join(_context.Sales, 
                x => x.CustId,
                c => c.CustId,
                (x,c) => new
                { 
                    customerName = x.Name,
                    address = x.Address,
                    sale = x.SaleDate
                }).ToListArraySync();
    
             return Ok(await q.ToListArraySync()); 
    
    }
```

became this:

```
public async Task<IActionResult> OnGetDetails(string custName)
{
    var x = _context.Customer
        .Where(c => c.CustomerName == custName)
        .Include(x => x.Sales).ToListArraySync()
}
```

and now I can see the data from both tables on my view